# why this error is happen not found raised button?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: I want to try raised button program]

This type of error is showing in all my program:

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Flutter/chirag/Go to second Page/go_to_secondpage_app/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "undefined_method",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/diagnostics/undefined_method",
            "path": "/diagnostics/undefined_method",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The method 'RaisedButton' isn't defined for the type 'SecondScreen'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'RaisedButton'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 44,
    "startColumn": 20,
    "endLineNumber": 44,
    "endColumn": 32
}]
```

Comment: Linking an image is worst way how to explain what you are doing, post it here as a code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please do not share screenshots. Share code instead. You can format it using three backticks as mentioned in the guidelines. Also, please, be more specific. It's kind-of hard to understand what you're asking and what the problem is. Try explaining what you want / expect and then share your solution via code.

Comment: Don't share screenshots or images of the code or errors. Kindly update your question properly with [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

please don't add image of codes,

About your issue RaisedButton is deprecated since release of Flutter 2 you can use ElevatedButton instead.

just like below:

```
   ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text(
          'Go to second screen',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          _navigateToSecondScreen(context);
        },
      )
```